# IOS objective c : if I have more than one navigation controller how to open viewController that not in the root navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to open view controller that at navigation controller but this navigation controller not the navigation controller for the root view

I tried that in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in the Appdelegate:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

MessagesTableViewController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"msg"];

//[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Why do you have more than one navigation controller?

Comment: I use SWRevealViewController for sidebar menu

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you don't have any UINavigationController at all? 

In that case you present the views modally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for more than one view controller. If so you can get the array of viewController in the parentViewController using this

> NSArray *childViewControllers =      self.navigationController.childViewControllers;

Then instantiate that one you want.